# FBSDKGraphRequest - Result = nil

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I installed a new version of Xcode (7.2 to 7.3), now I get an error (unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value).

Error code:

```
Error Code 8: error loading helper function: error: Couldn't lookup symbols:
      _memmove
```

My Code:

```
FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "/{user_id}/feed", parameters: ["fields":" id, message, picture, data, created_time"]).startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

//if error == 0 {
var resultdict = result as! NSDictionary!
            var data: NSArray = resultdict.objectForKey("data") as! NSArray

            for i in 0..<data.count {
                let valueDict: NSDictionary = data[i] as! NSDictionary
                let message = valueDict.objectForKey("message") as! String!

                let created_time = valueDict.objectForKey("created_time") as! String
                var df = NSDateFormatter()
                df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ"
                var date = df.dateFromString(created_time)
                df.dateFormat = "eee MMM dd yyyy"
                var dateStr = df.stringFromDate(date!)

                let picture = valueDict.objectForKey("picture") as! String
                let pictureURL = NSURL(string: picture)
                let pictureData = NSData(contentsOfURL: pictureURL!)
            }
           // }
        }
```

On Version 7.2 it worked, but now I get this error and my result is nil. I have tried to find a solution (used the search function on this website and found many solutions), but I get always the same error.

Any help?

UPDATE 1: I reinstalled Xcode, and now I have a new Error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
Printing description of error:
expression produced error: /var/folders/_4/qjkhmjw90ml2z5fd_gvmb23w0000gn/T/lldb/2724/expr2.swift:1:80: error: use of undeclared type 'Foundation'
$__lldb__DumpForDebugger(Swift.UnsafePointer<Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Foundation.NSError>>(bitPattern: 0x110bcbfa0).memory)
                                                                               ^~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/_4/qjkhmjw90ml2z5fd_gvmb23w0000gn/T/lldb/2724/expr2.swift:1:45: note: while parsing this '<' as a type parameter bracket
$__lldb__DumpForDebugger(Swift.UnsafePointer<Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Foundation.NSError>>(bitPattern: 0x110bcbfa0).memory)
```

UPDATE 2: Fixed it...

```
FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "/{user_id}/feed?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN", parameters: ["fields":" id, message, picture, data, created_time"]).startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
```

Comment: Did you check what `error` was?

Comment: Error Code 8: error loading helper function: error: Couldn't lookup symbols: _memmove - you mean this?